# reuse query result ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, alias

what I want is the following: I have a complex query, basically I compute a value, let's say price. Now I want to reuse this price in another query. But this two query should be in one query.

I tried it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 AS tbl LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 LEFT JOIN tbl ON t2.id=tbl.id) AS t3 ON tbl.id=t3.id
```

`t1` is the complex query. In this query I get the price value. Now, I want to join `t1` to `t2`, because I want to use the price value in the t3 query for further calculation. Then I join t3 to t1.

I thought, I pass an alias to t1 and then reuse it in the left join, but MS Access can't found tbl.

How could I solve this?

Comment: how about this?
SELECT t1 full outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    q1.* 
FROM 
    t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    q1
    ON t1.id = q1.id
```